# Keep ivy-initial-inputs-alist nil after counsel loaded

Tags: variables, ivy

I want to keep the alist `ivy-initial-inputs-alist` `nil` after `ivy` and `counsel` are loaded. Therefore, I have the following configuration:

```el
(use-package ivy
  :ensure t
  :config 

  ;; some keybindings

  (setq ivy-initial-inputs-alist nil))
```

However, this doesn't work after `counsel` is loaded. When I check the alist value, I get this:

```
Value:
((counsel-minor . "^+")
 (counsel-package . "^+")
 (counsel-org-capture . "^")
 (counsel-M-x . "^")
 (counsel-describe-function . "^")
 (counsel-describe-variable . "^"))
Original value was 
((org-refile . "^")
 (org-agenda-refile . "^")
 (org-capture-refile . "^")
 (Man-completion-table . "^")
 (woman . "^"))
```

meaning that the alist was set to `nil`, but `counsel` set it again later.

The only line that has something to do with `ivy-initial-inputs-alist` in `counsel.el` is:

```el
(cl-pushnew '(counsel-package . "^+") ivy-initial-inputs-alist :key #'car)
```

How can I make the `setq` persistent?

Comment: Unfortunately `counsel.el` currently calls the function `ivy-configure` defined in `ivy.el` in order to modify `ivy-initial-inputs-alist`, e.g. `(ivy-configure 'counsel-org-capture :initial-input "^")`. I say unfortunately because it's not very nice when simply loading a package can result in changes to user option values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it after `counsel` is loaded with:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'counsel
  (setq ivy-initial-inputs-alist nil))
```

See [`(elisp) Hooks for Loading`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html).

You can achieve the same thing with `use-package` as follows:

```el
(use-package counsel
  :defer t
  :config
  (setq ivy-initial-inputs-alist nil))
```